# QTMovie addImage:forDuration:withAttributes: can't be played by QuickTime Player X

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, qtkit

I have a mov file, that I am modifying by adding a track with an image to the beginning of the movie (using QTMovie's -addImage method). When I flatten such a movie (using -writeToFile: method of QTMovie), I get an another .mov file with this "watermark" in the beginning.
But when I try to play it, I end up with the message that QuickTime 7 needs to be installed in order to play such a file (original not-processed mov file didn't require QuickTime Player 7 and could be played fine in QT Player X which comes with Snow Leopard and Lion).

I am wondering whether it is possible to make this file be able to be played on QuickTime Player X? I wouldn't like the users of my application to be obliged to install this old version of the player. Furthermore, some applications like Final Cut Pro 7, Telestream Episode Engine encoder, Autodesk Smoke - just do not understand this "file format" correctly, after adding an image track to it.

Would it be possible to add an image as a **movie track**, not as an image track, somehow? Maybe using an old QT API? (QTKit seems to be raw still, anyway).

I am specifying "mpv4" as an image encoder (in the -addImage method), but still this watermark image is not considered as a movie track but rather as an image track encoded with the movie encoder.

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide more information. What codec used in the original movie? You can look it up in the inspector in QuickTime Player. How did you add a new track? `[QTMovie addImage:forDuration:withAttributes:]` does not add a new track, but an image to the existing one. How did you flatten the movie? Did you use 'QTMovieFlatten' attribute? What does the watermark look like?

Comment: Actually I just created a new movie ([[QTMovie alloc] initToWritableData:error:]), added an image (-addImage) to the movie (which apparently created a new track, at least an "image" kind, since there were 0 tracks in the beginning). Then I copied all the tracks from the original movie into this newly created one (iterated through all the tracks and invoked addTrack: for every track). Therefore I didn't use any special codec. QTPlayer's Movie inspector shows, besides an original movie track, a MPEG4 "video" track, which is my image encoded using 'mpv4' codec, and which is not a real video track

Comment: Then I saved this newly created movie using [QTMovie -writeToFile:@"newmovie.mov" withAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObj:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:QTMovieFlatten]] (this is the only way i found to be able to get all the tracks really written into the file, otherwise i just got "symlinks" inside a mov file, and a mov file of 4KB in size itself). And this mov file can be opened only with QuickTime 7 which may be irritating to end users, i guess. I was hoping I could convert an image into a **real video track**, not an image track. Maybe using QuickTime C API.

Comment: OK, I've got it. It is possible to make a movie with several video tracks, but it is unlikely many apps will understand that. Quicktime player will play this kind of movie by arranging the tracks according to their transformation matrices. VLC will not, it will play each track in a separate window. What exactly do you expect to get? Maybe you need just to add the image at the beginning of the existing video track?

Comment: Hello Davyd. I just would like to add an image to the beginning and to the end of the movie (this image should last for a few seconds, appearing as some kind of a trailer for both ends of the original movie), preserving the original video codec of the original video track if possible. At the moment VLC does not play my generated movie (as well, as some other applications). It would be excellent if I could add an image as a part of the existing video track. I don't know how, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a new movie and set the attribute to allow editing:

```
QTMovie* trailerMovie = [QTMovie movie];
[trailerMovie setAttribute:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:QTMovieEditableAttribute];
```

Select the time ranges in the original movie and append them to the new one:

```
QTTimeRange selectionRange = QTMakeTimeRange(QTMakeTime(...), QTMakeTime(...));
[originalMovie setSelection:selectionRange];
[trailerMovie appendSelectionFromMovie:originalMovie];
```

Add images:

```
[trailerMovie addImage:image forDuration:duration withAttributes:nil];
```

Save the movie to a file with QTMovieFlatten attribute:

```
[trailerMovie writeToFile:@"trailer.mov" withAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObj:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:QTMovieFlatten]]
```

Try this scenario, please let me know how it went.

Comment: Davyd, thank you for your answers. The thing is I need to add not only a trailer, but also a leader, which, when being added in the first place, creates its own track.

Comment: If I am appending the image to the end of the movie, I have only one resulting track (provided that I specify image encoder the same as used for the existing video track). But as soon as firstly add an image (even if the codec is the same as the movie's), I find myself having two tracks.

Comment: I would try to insert a short segment of movie to the new movie. This would create the tracks. The image should go to the existing track now. After it has been added delete the first segment. I admit it's kinda workaround, but it may save you time.